# Exporting a web from to MS word

Tags: c#

IS it possible to export a web page contents to MS word? If yes give some links to refer.

Answer (score 1):

^A ^C ^V ^S ?

Answer (score 0):

If you got installed MS Office in IE you can export page or tables to Excel. But if you press ctrl+A then you can copy-paste it into MS Word document. It won't look exactly same, because .docx is not .html.

Comment: But it doesn't copy the check box contents.

Answer (score 0):

Open in firefox and save page.
Open saved page in ms word.

Answer (score 0):

Exporting from the browser to ANYTHING will never be as good as the web page itself.

If you just want an image of the site, save an image or print the page to a PDF file.

If you actually want to edit the content, then **MS Word is NOT the right tool**.  Ask any developer in SO - MS Word generates the worst HTML we've ever seen.